# Get id from laravel array with multiple id's

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

im trying to fetch multiple Id's from one array for then using it on a query relationship.
This is what I tried:

```
    $following = $user->following;
    $followingId = $following->id;
```

I get this error:

```
'Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id'
```

If I log $following, I get the following array, as you can see I'm following 4 different users and I need to get those id's:

```
local.INFO: [{"id":32,"email":"test@mail.com","username":"test@mail.com","photo":"97dfebf4098c0f5c16bca61e2b76c373","cover_photo":"default-no-image.jpg","last_access":null,"activation_code":null,"is_sponsor":0,"is_admin":0,"displayname":null,"followers_amount":1,"winwins_amount":1,"pivot":{"follower_id":1,"followed_id":32}},{"id":69,"email":"fhamada@paginar.net","username":"fhamada@paginar.net","photo":"placeholder-square.jpg","cover_photo":"default-no-image.jpg","last_access":null,"activation_code":null,"is_sponsor":0,"is_admin":0,"displayname":null,"followers_amount":1,"winwins_amount":0,"pivot":{"follower_id":1,"followed_id":69}},{"id":79,"email":"sandrastun@gmail.com","username":"sandrastun@gmail.com","photo":"placeholder-square.jpg","cover_photo":"default-no-image.jpg","last_access":null,"activation_code":null,"is_sponsor":0,"is_admin":0,"displayname":null,"followers_amount":1,"winwins_amount":0,"pivot":{"follower_id":1,"followed_id":79}},{"id":101,"email":"cristobalalfonzo@outlook.com","username":"cristobalalfonzo@outlook.com","photo":"placeholder-square.jpg","cover_photo":"default-no-image.jpg","last_access":null,"activation_code":null,"is_sponsor":0,"is_admin":0,"displayname":null,"followers_amount":1,"winwins_amount":0,"pivot":{"follower_id":1,"followed_id":101}}]
```

Query relationship:

```
$activities = DB::table('notifications')
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'notifications.sender_id')
                ->join('followers', 'followed_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->join('user_details', 'user_details.id', '=', 'notifications.user_id')
                ->join('winwins', 'winwins.id', '=', 'object_id')
                ->leftJoin('groups', 'notifications.object_id', '=', 'groups.id')
            ->where('notifications.sender_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->orWhere('winwins.id', '=', 'notifications.object_id')
            ->orWhere('sender_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->orWhere('followers.followed_id', '=', $followingId)
            ->orderBy('sent_at', 'desc')
            ->skip($page * $amount)
            ->take($amount)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch multiple columns from a collection (e.g. multiple IDs from your `following` collection), use this:

```
$followingId = $following->pluck('id')->toArray();
```